# Creation of a Linked List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to created a linked list. However, the following code keeps printing only the last element of the list. Is there an error in my code? I think the problem lies in the "insert" method. I am not able to figure out why though.

```
import sys
import io


string = """4
2
3
4
1"""
sys.stdin = io.StringIO(string)


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class Solution:
    def display(self, head):
        current = head
        while current:
            print(current.data, end=' ')
            current = current.next

    # TODO: Code only prints the last element of data
    def insert(self, head, data):
        if head == None:
            head = Node(data)
            return head
        else:
            head.next = Node(data)
            return head.next


mylist = Solution()
T = int(input())
head = None
for i in range(T):
    data = int(input())
    head = mylist.insert(head, data)

mylist.display(head)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're losing the reference to the head of the list. You must keep the head and insert the new item at the end of the list

```
def insert(self,head,data): 
    if head == None:
        head = Node(data)
    else:
        current = head
        while current.next != None:
            current = current.next
        current.next = Node(data)
    return head
```

Answer (score 1):

You only keep a reference to the *end* of the chain (`head.next`), so yes, you'll only be able to display that last element.

You'll need to keep a reference to the *first* element (the real head):

```
mylist = Solution()
T = int(input())
current = head = None
for i in range(T):
    data = int(input())
    current = mylist.insert(head, data)
    if head is None:
        head = current
```